# Automatic compiler detection of the addition of the same object instance to a container in a loop

Tags: compiler-construction, static-analysis, error-detection

This is a dumb mistake:

```
List<Foo> fooList = new List<Foo>();
Foo f = new Foo();
while (something.Read()) {
    f.Fill(something.GetRecord());
    fooList.Add(f);
}
```

Of course, I should instantiate a new Foo inside the loop.

Can a compiler detect this kind of mistake at compile time?

To naïve eyes it looks like it should be able to detect this behavior (filling a List with instances of the same object in a loop). It should then issue a warning like "You are filling a container with the same instance more than once.".

So, how naïve am I being? Do you know of a language where something like this exists?

Comment: Now that I think about it, the compiler probably doesn't know about the semantics of a List<>, so it would pollute it with non core knowledge for no really important reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.

However, I don't think a tool or compiler would warn about this themselves, so you'd have to use a tool which can be extended with your own analyses. For Java, [FindBugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/) is such a tool. For C,C++, etc, [gcc 4.5 will allow plugins](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html) for people to write their own extensions, and [clang](http://clang.llvm.org/) from LLVM is designed for this too. There is also [Dehydra](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Dehydra) from Mozilla, again for C++. For MS languages, there is the [Phoenix framework](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/collaboration/focus/cs/phoenix.aspx).

So the question is, how do you write this analysis? Thats a little more tricky, and depends on the tool. But basically:

- you can detect loops fairly easily (look for "Strongly-connected components"),
- alias analysis can tell you if a particular variable or parameter refers to just one object, or many objects (look for "abstract objects", perhaps),
- you can find the right container using the static type of an object or variable.

So you could quite easily detect a call to `List<>.append(x)` in a loop, where x can refer to only one object.

Comment: The best solution to this problem is to take the longest possible route by custom-developing a compiler extension that converts all arrays to hashes?  Really?

Comment: @dannysauer: If you have a framework that supports loop-detection and alias analysis (ie all the frameworks I mentinoed), you should be able to do this in maybe 20 lines, certainly less than 50.

Comment: @dannysauer: Also, I don't know what you were expecting?

Answer (score 2):

What if you want to fill a List<> with multiple instances of an object? Would you need to decorate your code with `#pragma` so the compiler leaves you alone?

How would you even declare a class to have these sorts of restrictions? List<> is really nothing more than a C# class, you can decompile mscorlib.dll and see its full implementation. So to have this sort of knowledge, it would have to be hard coded somewhere. Attributes? That would be incredibly restricting. Special methods to validate your code? Would add overhead to your objects.

This kind of stuff is never (and I do mean never) used for a reason: the extremely small number of cases where it would help rather than hinder comes nowhere near to outweighing the very real cost it would require in both implementation difficulty (of the framework itself AND of your code) and performance hits (from overbloated objects that have to be moved around the memory as the GC does its thing).